# Pulumi - Exporting stack outputs is not working

Tags: javascript, typescript, docker, pulumi

How do I export a Pulumi Stack Output using Typescript?

I want the value of the Docker container's external port for use within a shell script.

After running `pulumi up`, `pulumi stack output` remains empty.

**CLI**

```bash
➜  pulumi up
...
➜  pulumi stack output
Current stack outputs (0):
    No output values currently in this stack
```

**index.ts**

```js
import './containers/my_container'
import './utils/network'
import './utils/volumes'
```

**my_container.ts**

```js
import * as docker from '@pulumi/docker'
import * as pulumi from '@pulumi/pulumi'

const container_name = `${pulumi.getProject()}-custom-name`

const my_container = pulumi
    .all([...])
    .apply(([...]) => {
        return new docker.Container(container_name, {
            name: container_name,
            ports: [
                {
                    internal: 8080,
                    external: 7000,
                },
            ],
            ...
        })
    })

export const custom_name_port = my_container.ports.apply(ports =>
    ports ? ports[0].external : undefined
)
export default my_container
```